# Removing marker from google maps

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

So I want to remove the marker ween it is clicked. I am using this code but nothing happens.

```
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
    marker.remove();
    return true;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tested and the remove() works..

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        marker.remove();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Do I need to add a return true statement?

Comment: return true if the listener has consumed the event (i.e., the default behavior should not occur), false otherwise (i.e., the default behavior should occur). The default behavior is for the camera to move to the map and an info window to appear.

Comment: Thanks I got it working. I was using an arraylist of marker so i guess that was conflicting with this.

Comment: Hey @Deacoy could you tell me more about what the return statement does? What is the default behaviour?

Comment: Read 2 comments higher ;)

Comment: Okay tested it. What would be a possible use case for making the camera move a few cm(on device)?

Comment: To move the camera I use map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude,longitude), 15), 3000, null);